# JWT valid according to JWT.io but invalid or malformed for Graph API

Tags: powershell, azure-active-directory, jwt, microsoft-graph-api

I've been working on a script that is creating a JWT for access to Microsoft Graph using a certificate installed locally.

It seems like there is a simpler solution by using the attribute `PrivateKey` from the certificate, but in some cases (depending on the key provider CNG or something else) it doesn't show up. I have to manually extract the private key with OpenSSL and then transform it into an `RSACryptoServiceProvider` to be able to sign the header+payload.

Now I'm struggling with a JWT token which seems to be valid according to jwt.io but is invalid or malformed for Microsoft.

Here is the error code :

```
Invoke-RestMethod : 
{
  "error": "invalid_request",
  "error_description": "AADSTS50027: JWT token is invalid or malformed.\r\nTrace ID:ed98bb58-8545-4667-acdd-8ce863303b00\r\nCorrelation ID: 722422ce-48d0-47ae-876d-3fb60a588e75\r\nTimestamp: 2021-02-12 13:53:47Z",
  "error_codes": [50027],
  "timestamp": "2021-02-12 13:53:47Z",
  "trace_id": "ed98bb58-8545-4667-acdd-8ce863303b00",
  "correlation_id": "722422ce-48d0-47ae-876d-3fb60a588e75",
  "error_uri": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/error?code=50027"
}

At D:\Scripts_Teams\QUAL\ReportingGraphAPI\Get-AuthTokenMSALDelegate.ps1:223 char:20
 + $accessToken = Invoke-RestMethod @PostSplat
 + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (System.Net.HttpWebRequest:HttpWebRequest) [Invoke-RestMethod], WebException
 + FullyQualifiedErrorId : WebCmdletWebResponseException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeRestMethodCommand ConvertFrom-Json : Cannot bind argument to parameter 'InputObject' because it is null.
 + 
At D:\Scripts_Teams\QUAL\ReportingGraphAPI\Get-AuthTokenMSALDelegate.ps1:225 char:41
 + $accessToken=$accessToken.content | ConvertFrom-Json
 + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [ConvertFrom-Json], ParameterBindingValidationException
 + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationErrorNullNotAllowed,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.ConvertFromJsonCommand
```

Here is the result I have from jwt.io:
[JWT.IO](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bP7uV.png)

And here is the code:

```
function Generate-JWT (
  [Parameter(Mandatory = $True)]
  [string]$Issuer = $null,
  [Parameter(Mandatory = $True)]
  [int]$ValidforMinutes = $null,
  [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)]
  $CertificateThumbprint,
  [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)]
  $TenantName
) {

  $Certificate = Get-Item "Cert:\LocalMachine\My\$CertificateThumbprint"
  # Create base64 hash of certificate
  $CertificateBase64Hash = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String($Certificate.GetCertHash())
  $tempfile = "C:\Temp\tempCert.pfx"
  Export-PfxCertificate -FilePath $tempfile -Cert $Certificate -Password (ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText "MyP@ssw0rd!" -Force)
  D:\Tools\OpenSSL\Bin\openssl.exe pkcs12 -in $tempfile -nocerts -out "C:\Temp\key.pem" -nodes -password pass:MyP@ssw0rd!
  D:\Tools\OpenSSL\Bin\openssl.exe rsa -in "C:\Temp\key.pem" -out "C:\Temp\key.key"

  $Algorithm = 'RS256'
  $type = 'JWT'
  $x5t = $CertificateBase64Hash -replace '\+', '-' -replace '/', '_' -replace '='
  $aud = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/$TenantName/oauth2/token"
  $jti = [guid]::NewGuid()

  # Create JWT timestamp for expiration
  $StartDate = (Get-Date "1970-01-01T00:00:00Z" ).ToUniversalTime()
  $JWTExpirationTimeSpan = (New-TimeSpan -Start $StartDate -End (Get-Date).ToUniversalTime().AddMinutes($ValidforMinutes)).TotalSeconds
  $JWTExpiration = [math]::Round($JWTExpirationTimeSpan, 0)
  # Create JWT validity start timestamp
  $NotBeforeExpirationTimeSpan = (New-TimeSpan -Start $StartDate -End ((Get-Date).ToUniversalTime())).TotalSeconds
  $NotBefore = [math]::Round($NotBeforeExpirationTimeSpan, 0)


  [hashtable]$JWTHeader = @{
    alg = $Algorithm
    typ = $type
    x5t = $x5t
  }
  [hashtable]$JWTPayLoad = @{
    aud = $aud
    exp = $JWTExpiration
    iss = $Issuer
    jti = $jti
    nbf = $NotBefore
    sub = $Issuer
  }

  $headerjson = $JWTHeader | ConvertTo-Json -Compress
  $payloadjson = $JWTPayLoad | ConvertTo-Json -Compress
    
  # Convert header and payload to base64
  $EncodedHeader = [Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetBytes($headerjson)).Split('=')[0].Replace('+', '-').Replace('/', '_')
  $EncodedPayload = [Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetBytes($payloadjson)).Split('=')[0].Replace('+', '-').Replace('/', '_')

  $ToSign = $EncodedHeader + "." + $EncodedPayload


  # Define RSA signature and hashing algorithm
  $RSAPadding = [Security.Cryptography.RSASignaturePadding]::Pkcs1
  $HashAlgorithm = [Security.Cryptography.HashAlgorithmName]::SHA256
    
  $opensslkeysource = Get-Content "D:\Scripts_Teams\QUAL\ReportingGraphAPI\opensslkey.cs" -Raw
  try {
    Add-Type -TypeDefinition $opensslkeysource
  }
  catch {
    if ($_.Exception -match "already exists") {
      Write-Verbose "The JavaScience.Win32 assembly (i.e. opensslkey.cs) is already loaded. Continuing..."
    }
  }
    
  $PemText = [System.IO.File]::ReadAllText("C:\Temp\key.key")
  $PemPrivateKey = [javascience.opensslkey]::DecodeOpenSSLPrivateKey($PemText)
  [System.Security.Cryptography.RSACryptoServiceProvider]$RSA = [javascience.opensslkey]::DecodeRSAPrivateKey($PemPrivateKey)
    

  # Create a signature of the JWT
  $Signature = [Convert]::ToBase64String(
    $RSA.SignData([System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetBytes($ToSign), $HashAlgorithm, $RSAPadding)
  ) -replace '\+', '-' -replace '/', '_' -replace '='


  $JWT = $ToSign + "." + $Signature
  return $JWT
}
```

And here is how it's been called :

```
$JWT = Generate-JWT  -Issuer $clientID -ValidforMinutes 60  -CertificateThumbprint $Thumbprint -TenantName $TenantName
  
$authBody = @{
  client_id             = $clientID
  client_assertion      = $JWT
  client_assertion_type = "urn:ietf:params:oauth:client-assertion-type:jwt-bearer"
  scope                 = "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default"
  grant_type            = "client_credentials"
    
}

# Use the self-generated JWT as Authorization
$Header = @{
  Authorization = "Bearer $JWT"
}


$uri = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/$tenantId/oauth2/v2.0/token"
# Splat the parameters for Invoke-Restmethod for cleaner code
$PostSplat = @{
  ContentType = 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
  Method      = 'POST'
  Body        = $authBody
  Uri         = $Uri
  Headers     = $Header
}

$accessToken = Invoke-RestMethod @PostSplat
```

Any ideas why this JWT would be rejected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding the issue, please refer to the following script

1. Export the certificate as PFX file from your store

```
$mypwd = ConvertTo-SecureString -String "1234" -Force -AsPlainText
 $Certificate = Get-Item "Cert:\LocalMachine\My\$CertificateThumbprint"
 $Certificate | Export-PfxCertificate -FilePath C:\mypfx.pfx -Password $mypwd
```

2. Upload certificate to Azure AD

```
$password= ConvertTo-SecureString "Password0123!" -AsPlainText -Force
$Cert = New-Object System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2
$Cert.Import("E:\cert\my.pfx", $password, [System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509KeyStorageFlags]::Exportable)

Connect-AzureAD

 $certKeyId = [Guid]::NewGuid()
   $certBase64Value = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String($Cert.GetRawCertData())
   $certBase64Thumbprint = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String($Cert.GetCertHash())

   # Add a Azure Key Credentials from the certificate for the daemon application
   $clientKeyCredentials = New-AzureADApplicationKeyCredential -ObjectId <> `
                                                                    -CustomKeyIdentifier "" `
                                                                    -Type AsymmetricX509Cert `
                                                                    -Usage Verify `
                                                                    -Value $certBase64Value `
                                                                    -StartDate $Cert.NotBefore `
                                                                    -EndDate $Cert.NotAfter
```

3. Create client asseration

```
$password= ConvertTo-SecureString "!" -AsPlainText -Force
$Cert = New-Object System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2
$Cert.Import("E:\cert\my.pfx", $password, [System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509KeyStorageFlags]::Exportable)

$appEndPoint = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/<tenantId>/v2.0"
$appClientID = "
<clientid>"
$jwtStartTimeUnix = ([DateTimeOffset](Get-Date).ToUniversalTime()).ToUnixTimeSeconds()
$jwtEndTimeUnix = ([DateTimeOffset](Get-Date).AddHours(1).ToUniversalTime()).ToUnixTimeSeconds()
$jwtID = [guid]::NewGuid().Guid

$headerjson = @{
    alg="RS256";
    typ="JWT";
    x5t=[System.Convert]::ToBase64String($Cert.GetCertHash())
} | ConvertTo-Json -Compress

$payloadjson = @{
    aud = $appEndPoint;
    exp = $jwtEndTimeUnix;
    iss = $appClientID;
    jti = $jwtID;
    nbf = $jwtStartTimeUnix;
    sub = $appClientID
} | ConvertTo-Json -Compress

$EncodedHeader = [Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetBytes($headerjson)).Split('=')[0].Replace('+', '-').Replace('/', '_')
$EncodedPayload = [Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetBytes($payloadjson)).Split('=')[0].Replace('+', '-').Replace('/', '_')

$ToSign = $EncodedHeader + "." + $EncodedPayload
$RSAPadding = [Security.Cryptography.RSASignaturePadding]::Pkcs1
$HashAlgorithm = [Security.Cryptography.HashAlgorithmName]::SHA256

$rsa=[System.Security.Cryptography.RSACryptoServiceProvider]::new()
$rsa.FromXmlString($Cert.PrivateKey.ToXmlString($true))
$Signature=$rsa.SignData([System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetBytes($ToSign), $HashAlgorithm, $RSAPadding)
$Signature = [Convert]::ToBase64String($Signature).Split('=')[0].Replace('+', '-').Replace('/', '_')

$JWT = $ToSign + "." + $Signature
```

4. Get token

```
$authBody = @{
  client_id             = $appClientID 
  client_assertion      = $JWT
  client_assertion_type = "urn:ietf:params:oauth:client-assertion-type:jwt-bearer"
  scope                 = "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default"
  grant_type            = "client_credentials"
    
}



$uri = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/<>/oauth2/v2.0/token"
# Splat the parameters for Invoke-Restmethod for cleaner code
$PostSplat = @{
  ContentType = 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
  Method      = 'POST'
  Body        = $authBody
  Uri         = $Uri

}

$accessToken = Invoke-RestMethod @PostSplat
$accessToken
```

[image]

For more details, please refer to

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-certificate-credentials

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/msal-net-client-assertions#signed-assertions

---

## Update

According to my test, the C# code is right. It may your script has some problems.
This is my script

```
$cert = Get-Item "Cert:\LocalMachine\My\<>"
Export-PfxCertificate -FilePath $tempfile -Cert $Certificate -Password (ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText "MyP@ssw0rd!" -Force)
$tempfile=""
D:\Tools\OpenSSL\Bin\openssl.exe pkcs12 -in $tempfile -nocerts -out "E:\cert\key.pem" -nodes -password pass:MyP@ssw0rd!
D:\Tools\OpenSSL\Bin\openssl.exe rsa -in "E:\cert\key.pem" -out "E:\cert\key.key"



$code= Get-Content -Path "D:\opensslkey.cs" -Raw

Add-Type -TypeDefinition $code -Language CSharp 

$pemString =Get-Content -Path E:\cert\key.key -Raw
$key=[JavaScience.opensslkey]::DecodeOpenSSLPrivateKey($pemString)

$rsa=[JavaScience.opensslkey]::DecodeRSAPrivateKey($key)


$appEndPoint = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/<tenantId>/oauth2/token"
$appClientID = "232a1406-b27b-4667-b8c2-3a865c42b79c"
$jwtStartTimeUnix = ([DateTimeOffset](Get-Date).ToUniversalTime()).ToUnixTimeSeconds()
$jwtEndTimeUnix = ([DateTimeOffset](Get-Date).AddHours(1).ToUniversalTime()).ToUnixTimeSeconds()
$jwtID = [guid]::NewGuid().Guid

$headerjson = @{
    alg="RS256";
    typ="JWT";
    x5t=[System.Convert]::ToBase64String($Cert.GetCertHash()) -replace '\+', '-' -replace '/', '_' -replace '='
} | ConvertTo-Json -Compress

$payloadjson = @{
    aud = $appEndPoint;
    exp = $jwtEndTimeUnix;
    iss = $appClientID;
    jti = $jwtID;
    nbf = $jwtStartTimeUnix;
    sub = $appClientID
} | ConvertTo-Json -Compress

$EncodedHeader = [Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetBytes($headerjson)).Split('=')[0].Replace('+', '-').Replace('/', '_')
$EncodedPayload = [Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetBytes($payloadjson)).Split('=')[0].Replace('+', '-').Replace('/', '_')

$ToSign = $EncodedHeader + "." + $EncodedPayload
$RSAPadding = [Security.Cryptography.RSASignaturePadding]::Pkcs1
$HashAlgorithm = [Security.Cryptography.HashAlgorithmName]::SHA256

$Signature=$rsa.SignData([System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetBytes($ToSign), $HashAlgorithm, $RSAPadding)
$Signature = [Convert]::ToBase64String($Signature).Split('=')[0].Replace('+', '-').Replace('/', '_')

$JWT = $ToSign + "." + $Signature

$authBody = @{
  client_id             = $appClientID 
  client_assertion      = $JWT
  client_assertion_type = "urn:ietf:params:oauth:client-assertion-type:jwt-bearer"
  scope                 = "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default"
  grant_type            = "client_credentials"
    
}



$uri = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/<tenantId>/oauth2/v2.0/token"
# Splat the parameters for Invoke-Restmethod for cleaner code
$PostSplat = @{
  ContentType = 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
  Method      = 'POST'
  Body        = $authBody
  Uri         = $Uri

}

$accessToken = Invoke-RestMethod @PostSplat
$accessToken.access_token
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hello Jim Xu!
Thank you, I saw this version using the attribute `PrivateKey`.
The issue is that I can't create another certificate as I have to use the internal PKI from my customer.
But your sample looks quite similar. Do you have an idea of what could cause the issue?

Comment: @StéphenWolf  when you read content from your key file, please try to remove the pemprivheader and pemprivfooter.

Comment: @StéphenWolf besides since you have use `Export-PfxCertificate` to export certificate as pfx, why not directly use `X509Certificate2` to read the pfx file to get private key.

Comment: I've just tried that, but then the JWT appears as unvalid on jwt.io and the same error is returned by Graph API.

Comment: I tried that too,
`PS D:\ReportingGraphAPI> $Cert | fl *`
`EnhancedKeyUsageList     : {Client Authentication (1.3.6.1.5.5.7.3.2), Server Authentication (1.3.6.1.5.5.7.3.1)}`
`DnsNameList              : {serverXXX}`
[...]
`HasPrivateKey            : True`
`**PrivateKey               : **`
`PublicKey                : System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.PublicKey`
[...]
The Private Key is empty

Comment: @StéphenWolf  I think you misunderstand my word. I said that after you run command `Export-PfxCertificate`,  it saves a pfx file on your disk. Then you run the command `$password= ConvertTo-SecureString "Password0123!" -AsPlainText -Force
$Cert = New-Object System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2
$Cert.Import("<your path>", $password, [System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509KeyStorageFlags]::Exportable)` to get private key.

Comment: Yes, I tried that, but the `privateKey` attribute of this X509Certificate2 certificate is empty after those 3 lines.
$Cert.PrivateKey is not showing anything

Comment: @StéphenWolf Could you please provide the code of `opensslkey.cs`

Comment: Sure, I downloaded it from here : https://raw.githubusercontent.com/sushihangover/SushiHangover-PowerShell/master/modules/SushiHangover-RSACrypto/opensslkey.cs
(I found it on a PowerShellGallery script : https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/encryptdecrypt/0.9.5/Content/Public%5CGet-PrivateKeyProperty.ps1)

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue. The JWT token and its claims were valid but I still kept getting "AADSTS50027: JWT token is invalid or malformed" error.

Turns out the x5t property was incorrect in my header which caused this error.

I computed the correct thumbprint in Java with this code:

```
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import java.security.cert.CertificateEncodingException;
import java.security.cert.X509Certificate;
import java.security.cert.CertificateFactory;
import java.util.Base64;

X509Certificate cert = getPublicKey();

String thumbprint = getThumbprint(cert); // base64 encoded thumbprint
    
X509Certificate getPublicKey() {
    try (FileInputStream inStream = new FileInputStream("{your .crt or .cer file here}")) {

        CertificateFactory cf = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509");
        X509Certificate cert = (X509Certificate) cf.generateCertificate(inStream);

        return cert;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("no file!");
        return null;
    }
}

String getThumbprint(X509Certificate cert) {
    try {
        return Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(getHash(cert));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return null;
    }
}

static byte[] getHash(X509Certificate cert) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, CertificateEncodingException {
    final MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-1");
    md.update(cert.getEncoded());
    return md.digest();
}
```